# How do I set a table header in Views 3?

Tags: 7, views

How exactly do I get a table header to appear above the table?
In views-view-table.tpl.php I can see a `<thead>` section, but what causes it to actually get rendered?
Where do I specify the column header text?
I tried various options in the settings page, but to no avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title can be defined from the Main views form.  Each column of the table is associated with a field.  If you select the field you can "add label" by selecting the checkbox and providing a name.  The Label will appear in the header of the table.

Comment: Thanks JoeS, I knew this was something silly simple [blush]

Comment: Fortunately, I have never been in your position !!!!! :D

Comment: Somehow I only believe in your original answer ;-) Thanks though!

Comment: I'm used to remove labels when setting up views. This is one of the few cases I needed to add them. Your solutions is pretty accurate to get table headers :)